# Adicionar +1 cada vez que uma child for chamada Fire Base

Tags: android, firebase

Olá, cá estou eu novamente com a saga do fire base :p,

Então como posso fazer para adicionar +1 na `child Users` quando alguém entrar numa atividade , no caso perfil de um usuário, quero fazer igual tem no perfil aqui da comunidade, Agradeço desde já.

Creio que este seja o ponto de partida

```
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mPost_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("uidusuario");

        mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mDatabase.child(mPost_key).child("visitasperfil").setValue();
```

Comment: e qual exatamente a duvida? So mexi no firebase para web, mas o processo acredito ser o mesmo, como ja fez o "select" do usuario é so da um `update()` incrementando o valor, veja o [doc do update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) por enquanto faço assim, tambem estou na procura de uma melhor forma se existir.

Comment: pelo oque eu entendi uptade manda um valor pre definido

Comment: preciso que seja constante, por enquanto vou mandar child para o firebase qundo criar o perfil então quando um usuario ver o perfil mada seu `uid` para essa child ai vou usar getChildrenCount pra contar o numero de itens na child,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      mDatabaseVisitas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Log.e(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key)),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

            for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Log.e(String.valueOf(snap.child(currentUserId).toString()),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
                mVisitas.setText(dataSnapshot.child(currentUserId).getChildrenCount() + "");
            }}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabaseVisitas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mDatabaseVisitas.child(currentUserId).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("true");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```